# Difference between two optional syntaxes in Swift

Tags: swift, optional-variables

What is difference between

```
self?.profile!.id!
```

and

```
(self?.profile!.id!)!
```

XCode converts first to second.

Comment: My speculation is that the original value is a **double optional**.

Comment: Check this: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one contains `self?` which means `self` is optional, leads to let related properties  (`profile!.id!` in your case) related to the existence of the `self` which is [**Optional Chaining**](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html):

> Optional chaining is a process for querying and calling properties,
>   methods, and subscripts on an optional that might currently be nil. If
>   the optional contains a value, the property, method, or subscript call
>   succeeds; **if the optional is nil, the property, method, or subscript**
>   **call returns `nil`**. **Multiple queries can be chained together, and the**
>   **entire chain fails gracefully if any link in the chain is nil.**

To make it more simpler, you could think of `id!` nullity is also optional, even if you force unwrapping it, because it is related to the existence of `self`; If `self` is `nil`, `profile` and `id` will be also `nil` implicitly because they are related to the existence of `self`.

Mentioning: `(self?.profile!.id!)!` means that the whole value of the chain would be force wrapped.

Note that implementing:

```
self!.profile!.id!
```

leads to the same output of

```
(self?.profile!.id!)!
```

since `self!` is force unwrapped, the value of `id` would not be related to the nullity of `self` because the compiler assumes that `self` will always has a value.

However, this approach is *unsafe*, you should go with optional binding.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you are using too many question and exclamation marks!!!

Practically there is no difference. The result is a forced-unwrapped optional.

Usually Xcode suggests that syntax if the result of the last item of the chaining is a non-optional so the exclamation mark would cause an error for example

```
text?.count!
```

Then Xcode suggests

```
(text?.count)!
```

but in this case *be brave* and write

```
text!.count
```